# Disable Line-Change after Comment

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to disable the automatic line-change in PhpStorm after commenting a line?

After commenting, the cursor jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not possible.
Someone has produced a workaround using marcos though: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435#comment=27-1834754